# Java EJB application - why am I getting a 404 error when trying to make a GET call to my controller?

Tags: java, servlets, get, ejb

I have a Java EJB application I have been developing. I'm putting the final touches on it before moving it to production and, of course, broke it somehow. No clue what happened and I've been banging my head against a wall for several hours now. Hoping for some help.

I'm using a Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.0 server. Targeted runtime JBoss EAP 7.0 and EJB Module is 3.2. I don't believe I screwed up anything in the build path, but I guess that's a possibility. No web.xml file since I can use annotations.

The application launches and can be accessed in the browser. The UI loads, but the first call to the server fails:

```
$.get("Controller?action=login&userid=" + params.get('userid') + "&timestamp=" + getDateStamp(), function(authText) {...});
```

I get the error:

> XHRGET
> http://localhost/OfflineInspections/Controller?action=login&userid=9043&timestamp=20231012_162723
> [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]

In my controller:

```
@WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Controller() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        
        Util.log("v" + Util.VERSION + " Get Request. Action: " + action);
        System.out.println("testing");
...
```

"testing" doesn't show up on the console.

I'm out of ideas. Where else can I look?

EDIT:

Server log:

```
17:08:36,521 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.4.Final-redhat-1
17:08:36,648 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1
17:08:36,700 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.1.3.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.16.Final-redhat-1) starting
17:08:37,151 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
17:08:37,159 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
17:08:37,160 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.10.Final-redhat-1
17:08:37,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found OfflineInspections.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called OfflineInspections.ear.dodeploy
17:08:37,187 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
17:08:37,192 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO version 3.5.5.Final-redhat-1
17:08:37,195 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.5.Final-redhat-1
17:08:37,203 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.0.25.Final-redhat-1
17:08:37,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
17:08:37,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
17:08:37,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
17:08:37,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
17:08:37,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
17:08:37,208 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
17:08:37,212 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-1
17:08:37,221 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.9.Final-redhat-1)
17:08:37,227 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
17:08:37,230 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.SP7-redhat-1 starting
17:08:37,231 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
17:08:37,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
17:08:37,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:08:37,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 7.0)
17:08:37,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = sqlserver2008
17:08:37,270 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\JBOSS-EAP70/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
17:08:37,427 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 48 core threads with 384 task threads based on your 24 available processors
17:08:37,450 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.7.Final-redhat-1
17:08:37,461 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
17:08:37,462 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
17:08:37,467 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYPAT0050: JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
17:08:37,473 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow AJP listener ajp-default listening on 0.0.0.0:8009
17:08:37,473 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:80
17:08:37,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\JBOSS-EAP70\standalone\deployments
17:08:37,478 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "OfflineInspections.ear" (runtime-name: "OfflineInspections.ear")
17:08:37,503 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMSGAMQ0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO.
17:08:37,520 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
17:08:37,530 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=C:\JBOSS-EAP70\standalone\data\activemq\journal,bindingsDirectory=C:\JBOSS-EAP70\standalone\data\activemq\bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\JBOSS-EAP70\standalone\data\activemq\largemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\JBOSS-EAP70\standalone\data\activemq\paging)
17:08:37,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) IJ020018: Enabling <validate-on-match> for java:/OfflineInspCTZDS
17:08:37,543 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
17:08:37,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "OfflineInspections-WebAppMin.war")
17:08:37,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "OfflineInspections-EJBApp.jar")
17:08:37,547 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
17:08:37,549 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/OfflineInspCTZDS]
17:08:37,549 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
17:08:37,567 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
17:08:37,567 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
17:08:37,748 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
17:08:37,779 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.10.Final-redhat-1 (Apache CXF 3.1.13.redhat-1) 
17:08:37,826 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
17:08:37,826 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
17:08:37,826 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
17:08:37,826 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
17:08:37,856 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.OfflineInspections.ear.OfflineInspections-EJBApp.jar" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.codec") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
17:08:37,857 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.OfflineInspections.ear" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.codec") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
17:08:37,880 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221007: Server is now live
17:08:37,880 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 1.5.5.012-redhat-1 [default, nodeID=0c3f2876-09ad-11eb-9f33-00155d0cd203] 
17:08:37,882 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ122005: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected for "http-connector" connector. Switching to "DESKTOP-OQ0COFF". If this new address is incorrect please manually configure the connector to use the proper one.
17:08:37,891 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
17:08:37,896 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) AMQ221003: Deploying queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
17:08:37,899 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) AMQ221003: Deploying queue jms.queue.DLQ
17:08:37,899 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
17:08:37,912 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
17:08:37,935 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-6) Resource adaptor started
17:08:37,935 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-6) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
17:08:37,936 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
17:08:37,936 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
17:08:37,940 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-5) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.11.Final-redhat-1
17:08:38,044 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
17:08:38,099 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/OfflineInspections' for server 'default-server'
17:08:38,103 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host"),
    ("filter-ref" => "contentsecuritypolicy")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.filter.contentsecuritypolicy"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.filter-ref.contentsecuritypolicy is missing [jboss.undertow.filter.contentsecuritypolicy]"]
}
17:08:38,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "OfflineInspections.ear" (runtime-name : "OfflineInspections.ear")
17:08:38,107 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.undertow.filter.contentsecuritypolicy (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.filter-ref.contentsecuritypolicy] 

17:08:38,130 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
17:08:38,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
17:08:38,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
17:08:38,132 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: JBoss EAP 7.1.3.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.16.Final-redhat-1) started (with errors) in 1764ms - Started 517 of 747 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 380 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

EDIT 2

I tried adding a new controller with just a doGet that outputs a single line to the console. I tried a call from the front end and am getting a 404 there are well. Somehow the application isn't recognizing my controllers.

Could this be an issue with a mapped library or something?

Comment: Are there any special messages on deployment? Usually when something does not work, you can see it in the logs there. And sometimes really strange things can happen with out-of-date certificates. For example, 5 years ago, when certificates ran out of date on a glassfish JEE server, the whole console and some internal services would shut down. From 1 moment to the next everything stopped working... Maybe something like that's happening here too...? Also, let your IDE generate a proper `serialVersionUID`. JEE is full of surprises.

Comment: @JayC667 I don't think there is anything in the deployment that wasn't there prior to me screwing it up. I added the log above. I commented out the "private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;" and eclipse gave me a warning. If I use Eclipse's "Add generated serial version ID" it adds the same line of code.

Comment: Go back in your commit history and test older versions until you find the change that broke it.

Comment: Finally got it. I compared the build path and runtime to an older version and got these lined up. I also switched the Runtime JRE to Execution Environment on my server. I've added and deleted the server a million times, but somehow this random combination of things fixed the issue. On launch, it finally through an error with the new controller I added, so it actually recognized the code. I fixed the error and the call went through. Not entirely sure what changed, but it is recognizing my code changes again.

Comment: @rphello101 It is near impossible that Eclipse will generate "1L" for `serialVersionUID`. That only happens if there is a syntactic error inside the file. "1L" or "-1L". Now that you've fixed it, let Eclipse generate it anew. I bet that some proper UID is generated this time ;-)

Comment: @JayC667 you are indeed correct. It now has quite a long number